# Повторное использование кода DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Доброй ночи, столкнулся с такой проблемой: в моей программе есть 2 кнопки с похожим функционалом, при клике на "кнопка1" открывается DialogFragmen в котором мы выбираем изображение для "кнопка1", а при клике на "кнопка2"  выбираем изображение для "кнопка2". 
Вопрос: как можно узнать какая кнопка вызвала DialogFragment, а вернее как можно получить её id? 
Спасибо.

Метод onClick:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnDlg1:
            dlg1 = new dlg1();
            dlg1.show(getFragmentManager(), "dlg1");
            break;

        case R.id.btnDlg2:
            dlg1 = new dlg1();
            dlg1.show(getFragmentManager(), "dlg1");
            break;}}
```

Обработчик нажатия в DialogFragment:

```
        case R.id.btnRub:
            MainActivity.btnDlg1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ru);
            index = ParseTask.map.get("RUB");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, Double.toString(index));
            MainActivity.setMultiplier(index);
            dismiss();
            break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял то вам могут помочь аргументы фрагментов. В `DialogFragment` в качестве аргумента можно передавать `id` кнопки. Небольшой пример:

*Код вызова диалога*

```
private static final String DIALOG_TAG = "dialog_tag";
...

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnDlg1:
            showDialogFragment(R.id.btnDlg1);
            break;
        case R.id.btnDlg2:
            showDialogFragment(R.id.btnDlg2);
            break;
    }
}

private void showDialogFragment(int buttonId){
    FirstDialogFragment dialogFragment = FirstDialogFragment.newInstance(buttonId);
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TAG);
}
```

*Код фрагмента диалога*

```
public class FirstDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private static final String EXTRA_BUTTON_ID = "button_id";

    public static FirstDialogFragment newInstance(int buttonId) {
        FirstDialogFragment frag = new FirstDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(EXTRA_BUTTON_ID, buttonId);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int buttonId = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_BUTTON_ID);
        switch (buttonId){
            case R.id.btnDlg1:
                //first button pressed
                break;
            case R.id.btnDlg2:
                //second button pressed
                break;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Надеюсь суть вы поняли.

**PS**: Используйте константы для хранения идентификаторов, это исключает ошибки при опечатках.